# Athlon 64 single core and dual core compability

Tags: cpu, compatibility, core

I'm trying to revive an old MSI K9A board (MS-7280). According to the error leds it seems the CPU is defect (according to the manual).

I can't find any specific references to the CPU compatibility "core wise" on the MSI site [here](https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/support/K9A_Platinum.html#support-cpu). It doesn't specify single/multi core, does it mean it supports both or just the single core?

Might there be any compatibility issues replacing an AMD Athlon 64 3800+ single core CPU ([ADA3800IAA4CW](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%203800%2B%20-%20ADA3800IAA4CW%20(ADA3800CWBOX).html)) by the dual core CPU ([ADA3800IAA4CU - you need to put in the CPU-number in the search field](http://www.cpu-world.com/cgi-bin/IdentifyPart.pl))?

Comment: Why can't you just do a like for like replacement or ask MSI?

Comment: @DavidPostill Because I only have the dual core CPU as replacement, and so far I haven't received any answer from MSI besides being refered to the web site. Either way, I'm not really looking for a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page you linked](https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/support/K9A_Platinum.html#support-cpu) lists several X2 processors. [Athlon X2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_64_X2) is AMDs original dual core processor line.

> The Athlon 64 X2 is the first native dual-core desktop CPU designed by AMD.

So for dual core you have the following options:

```
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5600+   200     2.90    1M  N/A     G2  76      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5800+   200     3.00    1M  N/A     G2  76      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        BE-2300     200     1.90    1M  N/A     G1  45      7280v16.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        BE-2300     200     1.90    1M  N/A     G2  45      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        BE-2350     200     2.10    1M  N/A     G1  45      7280v16.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        BE-2350     200     2.10    1M  N/A     G2  45      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        BE-2400     200     2.30    1M  N/A     G2  45      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        3600+   200     1.90    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4000+   200     2.10    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4200+   200     2.20    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4200+   200     2.20    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4400+   200     2.30    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4400+   200     2.30    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4400+   200     2.30    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4600+   200     2.40    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4800+   200     2.50    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        4800+   200     2.50    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5200+   200     2.70    1M  N/A     G1  65      7280v15.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5200+   200     2.70    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v17.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5400+   200     2.80    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        5600+   200     2.90    1M  N/A     G2  65      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Brisbane        6000+   200     3.10    1M  N/A     G2  89      7280v18.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     F2  89      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     F2  89      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     F3  89      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5200+   200     2.60    2M  N/A     F2  89      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5200+   200     2.60    2M  N/A     F3  89      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5400+   200     2.80    1M  N/A     F3  89      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5600+   200     2.80    2M  N/A     F3  89      7280v13.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         6000+   200     3.00    2M  N/A     F3  89      7280v16.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         3800+   200     2.00    1M  N/A     F2  35      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         3600+   200     2.00    512K    N/A     F2  65      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         3800+   200     2.00    1M  N/A     F2  65      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         4600+   200     2.40    1M  N/A     F2  65      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         4800+   200     2.40    2M  N/A     F2  65      7280v12.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         5000+   200     2.60    1M  N/A     F3  65      7280v16.zip
Athlon X2   Windsor         6400+   200     3.20    2M  N/A     F3  125         7280v17.zip
```

There are sat least a couple of X2 3800+ processors in that list.

Comment: Ok thanks I wasn't aware that X2 stands for dual core, thats why there is no info about single/multi core, so +1. How ever I'm trying to find out if the specific processor is compatible, but ADA3800IAA4CU is not on the list, is it?!

Comment: @Albin I cannot find anything about ADA3800IAA4CU outside of shady looking "we stock everything you search for" sites. There is a 5CU part, which according to your site the 5 denotes 2 x 512KB cache which makes sense given a single core has 512KB. Either your part is an early engineering sample that was never officially released or it was a typo. I would recommend looking for a [ADA3800IAA5CU](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%20X2%203800+%20-%20ADA3800IAA5CU%20(ADA3800CUBOX).html) in all honesty. Is the part you have something in your hands or is it a part you are looking for?

Comment: No, different CPU is not an option, but never mind...  I just wasn't careful enough and misread the CPU ID it is ...AA5... not ...AA4... no wonder I couldn't find it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Albin the only thing that concerns me is that the ADA processors are 89W, while the mobo page lists only 65 (ADO) and 35W compatibility. It might simply be that you need to be sure you have a good cooler, as the core architecture looks the same and everything else seems to match up. The mobo has compatibility with 89W chips so I don't think it should be a problem, might just be a less efficient chip for some reason. It wouldn't be the first time that a manufacturer forgot to list *every* variant of processor.

Comment: good point, I didn't notice that, thank you!